# Changes in the model file not reflected in EMF editor after first time

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf, emf

In my RCP application I have used EMF resources.Whenever I create a model in the editor, the respective model XMI file is being created.

Now I wrote a code to change the XMI file programatically which in turn should reflect the changes in the editor part.

When I make changes to XMI file and open the editor for the first time in the application, the changes are being reflected but if i make changes once again 
 and reopen the editor the changes are not being reflected.I even tried adding `ResourceChangeListener` and reloading the resources but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in the default editor how it's basically done ?
For such questions, I always refer to the editor generated by EMF to look what i missed.